# Using date command with multiple variables

Tags: bash, date, variables

I have three variables $year $month and $day. Each of them gather the input from a user like: 
myday 20160303 
or 
myday 2016 03 03
in different ways, I used multiple "if" statements to save in this example the first yyyy under year variable, mm under month and day accordingly.
I need to use them to find out the day of the week. What I have at this moment is

```
nn=`date --date="$1" +"%A"`

echo "$nn"
```

It works with input like 20160404 but if the user type 3 arguments how can I use all three variables correctly in a date command to show the day of the week?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work in linux date version (GNU coreutils), not sure about Mac OS X. `date.bash` looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
date -d "$1$2$3" +%Y-%m-%d
```

assign exe permission :

```
chmod u+x date.bash
```

execute:

```
]# ./date.bash 2016 06 24
2016-06-24

]# ./date.bash 20160624
2016-06-24

]#./date.bash 2016 0624
2016-06-24
```

For Mac OS X, you can use the following syntax in `date.bash`

```
#!/bin/bash
date -j -f "%Y%m%d" "$1$2$3" +%Y-%m-%d
```

In all the above examples, I used `+%Y-%m-%d` for the format. You can replace that with `+%A` as you are doing to get the name of the day.

Note: For Mac OS, `./date.bash 2016-06-24` will not work, while in Linux it would work.

Comment: This has an extra advantage that if there are no arguments, it prints `now` :)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to combine three arguments into one, it's simply:

```
"$1$2$3"
```

This will turn `2016 03 03` into `20160303`

Comment: I was trying to put them in brackets but didn't think it is that easy, thank you